# Accessing application.conf in GlobalSettings onStart (Play Framework)

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I am using Java / Play Framework 2.1.0.

I have found other questions asking how to access application.conf, and I tried two methods:

```
Play.application().configuration().getString("my.thing");
```

and

```
ConfigFactory.load().getString("my.thing");
```

In both cases I dont get anything back. I am trying to do this in onStart of my Global class. Maybe onStart happens before configuration is loaded?

How can I access values in application.conf from within onStart? (Or, to be more precise, how do I access values in myapp.conf which is included in application.conf)

Comment: For the first method, make sure you are using `play.Play` and not `play.api.Play`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I read another post that said play.api.Play is for scala. I havent gotten this to work but I think config just isnt available yet in onStart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you verify that your `onStart` is getting called at all?

The configuration values are loaded and accessible at that point. In fact, you are getting the `play.Application` instance passed as an argument, so you can just do this:

```
  public void onStart(Application app)
  {
    super.onStart(app);
    String value = app.configuration().getString("my.thing");
    // do something with value
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working now. It might have been a problem with my configuration being split into multiple conf files and then one of them possibly not found in CLASSPATH. I'm not sure how to debug onStart yet but just printing to the log did the trick (as it often does).